# Python 3 , Windows 7 :ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, json, url, python-3.x

**Edited :**

**I use corporate env , on my home env the script works ok**

I'm trying to get response from some weather site . I made a simple python script .

```
import urllib.request
import json

req=urllib.request.Request("http://api.wunderground.com/api/e0b319c6f7e8115a/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json")
 response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
 data = json.loads(response.read().decode())  #<--according to @falsetru fix
 print (data)
```

**When I paste the URL into browser, I get response , but in python  I get error**
Please help

Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\weather.py", line 14, in <module>
response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 455, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1202, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1177, in do_open
r = h.getresponse()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 371, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works as expected, except that the response bytes should be decoded because [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) expects a `str` object.

**UPDATE**

You need to configure proxy in Python code like the browser. You can use [`urllib.request.Request.set_proxy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.set_proxy), or [`urllib.request.ProxyHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler):

---

```
import urllib.request
import json

req = urllib.request.Request("http://api.wunderground.com/api/e0b319c6f7e8115a/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json")
req.set_proxy('PROXY_HOST:PROXY_PORT', 'http')  # <---
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = json.loads(response.read().decode())  # <----
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response . I added decode to script , same error . I think the error somehow related to my env : Win 7, python 3.4.2 , IDLE

Comment: @Toren, I just tried the code in the exactly same environment, and it works: http://i.imgur.com/Z9IHQaE.png

Comment: Your code is working on my home env ! unfortunately on my enterprise env the error still exists . Maybe I need to wrap the code somehow ? same url in browser on enterprise env is OK

Comment: @Toren, Did you configure the browser special way? For example, something like proxy.

Comment: According to configuration the internet explorer configured with proxy script

Comment: @Toren, Try `req.set_proxy('proxy_host:proxy_port', 'http')` before call `urllib.request.urlopen`.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot for support !

Comment: @Toren, You're welcome. I'm glad to be helpful to you. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and make your code much simpler:

```
import requests

proxies = {
"http": "http://ip:port",
"https": "http://ip:port",
}

req = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/e0b319c6f7e8115a/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",proxies=proxies)

data = req.json()
print(data)


{'current_observation': {'weather': 'Clear', 'wind_string': 'From the WSW at 4.6 MPH Gusting to 4.9 MPH', 'heat_index_string': 'NA', 'precip_1hr_in': '0.00', 'local_epoch': '1420127354', 'feelslike_string': '15 F (-9 C)', 'wind_degrees': 248, 'observation_epoch': '1420127338', 'local_tz_offset': '-0600', 'feelslike_c': '-9', 'UV': '0.0', 'visibility_km': '16.1', 'visibility_mi': '10.0', 'wind_kph': 7.4, 'ob_url': 'http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=41.981174,-91.682632', 'temp_f': 21.7, 'wind_gust_kph': '7.9', 'icon': 'clear', 'heat_index_c': 'NA', 'local_tz_short': 'CST', 'observation_time': 'Last Updated on January 1, 9:48 AM CST', 'pressure_mb': '1019', 'image': {'link': 'http://www.wunderground.com', 'url': 'http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png', 'title': 'Weather Underground'}, 'wind_gust_mph': '4.9', 'icon_url': 'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif', 'temperature_string': '21.7 F (-5.7 C)', 'dewpoint_f': 15, 'pressure_trend': '0', 'display_location': {'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'latitude': '41.97171021', 'country': 'US', 'zip': '52401', 'wmo': '99999', 'country_iso3166': 'US', 'longitude': '-91.65871429', 'elevation': '223.00000000', 'magic': '1', 'state': 'IA', 'full': 'Cedar Rapids, IA', 'state_name': 'Iowa'}, 'station_id': 'KIACEDAR22', 'heat_index_f': 'NA', 'forecast_url': 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/IA/Cedar_Rapids.html', 'dewpoint_string': '15 F (-9 C)', 'pressure_in': '30.09', 'wind_dir': 'WSW', 'precip_today_metric': '0', 'windchill_f': '15', 'wind_mph': 4.6, 'observation_time_rfc822': 'Thu, 01 Jan 2015 09:48:58 -0600', 'precip_1hr_metric': ' 0', 'local_tz_long': 'America/Chicago', 'windchill_string': '15 F (-9 C)', 'local_time_rfc822': 'Thu, 01 Jan 2015 09:49:14 -0600', 'dewpoint_c': -9, 'solarradiation': '0', 'relative_humidity': '75%', 'nowcast': '', 'observation_location': {'country_iso3166': 'US', 'longitude': '-91.682632', 'city': 'Ellis Park Time Check, Cedar Rapids', 'latitude': '41.981174', 'elevation': '728 ft', 'state': 'Iowa', 'country': 'US', 'full': 'Ellis Park Time Check, Cedar Rapids, Iowa'}, 'estimated': {}, 'history_url': 'http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KIACEDAR22', 'precip_today_string': '0.00 in (0 mm)', 'feelslike_f': '15', 'precip_today_in': '0.00', 'windchill_c': '-9', 'temp_c': -5.7, 'precip_1hr_string': '0.00 in ( 0 mm)'}, 'location': {'tz_long': 'America/Chicago', 'type': 'CITY', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'country': 'US', 'requesturl': 'US/IA/Cedar_Rapids.html', 'nearby_weather_stations': {'pws': {'station': [{'id': 'KIACEDAR22', 'neighborhood': 'Ellis Park Time Check', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 1, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 2, 'lon': -91.682632, 'lat': 41.981174}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR41', 'neighborhood': 'PUBLIC HEALTH', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 1, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 2, 'lon': -91.687798, 'lat': 41.9767}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR28', 'neighborhood': 'Indian Hill Rd', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 2, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 4, 'lon': -91.617867, 'lat': 42.001289}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR35', 'neighborhood': 'NorthEast Cedar Rapids', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 2, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 4, 'lon': -91.670929, 'lat': 42.014057}, {'id': 'MUP022', 'neighborhood': 'MesoWest OTIS1 IA US UPR', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 3, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 5, 'lon': -91.592079, 'lat': 41.961639}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR46', 'neighborhood': 'Wolf River Lane Northwest', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 3, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 5, 'lon': -91.722778, 'lat': 41.991871}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR37', 'neighborhood': 'College Farms', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 3, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 6, 'lon': -91.616905, 'lat': 41.927353}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR47', 'neighborhood': 'Twin Pines', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 4, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 6, 'lon': -91.694054, 'lat': 42.028618}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO18', 'neighborhood': 'Marion, IA south side', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 4, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 7, 'lon': -91.596588, 'lat': 42.026505}, {'id': 'MD2681', 'neighborhood': 'APRSWXNET Cedar Rapids IA US', 'city': 'Hiawatha', 'distance_mi': 4, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 8, 'lon': -91.649834, 'lat': 42.0453}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR39', 'neighborhood': 'Oak Valley - Deer View Rd', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 5, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 9, 'lon': -91.725883, 'lat': 42.035496}, {'id': 'KIACEDAR25', 'neighborhood': 'The Howling Wolves', 'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'distance_mi': 5, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 9, 'lon': -91.655243, 'lat': 42.053856}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO13', 'neighborhood': 'Deer Valley', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 5, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 9, 'lon': -91.567619, 'lat': 42.023415}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO6', 'neighborhood': 'Pheasant Ridge Ct', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 5, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 9, 'lon': -91.601463, 'lat': 42.049641}, {'id': 'MRCRI4', 'neighborhood': 'IADOT Cedar Rapids (US30)', 'city': 'Ely', 'distance_mi': 6, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 10, 'lon': -91.549896, 'lat': 41.9259}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO15', 'neighborhood': 'Windemere 2nd Addition', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 6, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 11, 'lon': -91.572784, 'lat': 42.047874}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO17', 'neighborhood': 'Edgebrook Estates', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 6, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 11, 'lon': -91.58535, 'lat': 42.055588}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO8', 'neighborhood': '', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 6, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 11, 'lon': -91.559654, 'lat': 42.041698}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO19', 'neighborhood': 'Hunters Field', 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 7, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 12, 'lon': -91.592049, 'lat': 42.068359}, {'id': 'KIAMARIO14', 'neighborhood': "Berry's Run", 'city': 'Marion', 'distance_mi': 7, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 12, 'lon': -91.597679, 'lat': 42.077976}, {'id': 'KIASWISH5', 'neighborhood': 'Swisher', 'city': 'Swisher', 'distance_mi': 8, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 14, 'lon': -91.69252, 'lat': 41.847839}, {'id': 'KIATODDV2', 'neighborhood': 'Midway, IA', 'city': 'Toddville', 'distance_mi': 9, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 15, 'lon': -91.700241, 'lat': 42.105621}, {'id': 'KIAATKIN3', 'neighborhood': 'Ridgeview Estates', 'city': 'Atkins', 'distance_mi': 9, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 16, 'lon': -91.853317, 'lat': 41.988167}, {'id': 'KIASPRIN1', 'neighborhood': 'Whittier', 'city': 'Springville', 'distance_mi': 12, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 20, 'lon': -91.461136, 'lat': 42.082436}, {'id': 'KIALISBO2', 'neighborhood': '', 'city': 'Lisbon', 'distance_mi': 13, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 22, 'lon': -91.393059, 'lat': 41.920174}, {'id': 'KIANORTH5', 'neighborhood': 'Cedar Springs - North Liberty', 'city': 'North Liberty', 'distance_mi': 14, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 23, 'lon': -91.595421, 'lat': 41.767082}, {'id': 'KIAOXFOR4', 'neighborhood': 'Green Castle', 'city': 'Oxford', 'distance_mi': 14, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 24, 'lon': -91.718925, 'lat': 41.753613}, {'id': 'KIACENTR2', 'neighborhood': '', 'city': 'Central City', 'distance_mi': 15, 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'distance_km': 25, 'lon': -91.654335, 'lat': 42.198334}]}, 'airport': {'station': [{'city': 'Cedar Rapids', 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'lon': '-91.70769501', 'icao': 'KCID', 'lat': '41.88240051'}, {'city': 'Iowa City', 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'lon': '-91.54306030', 'icao': 'KIOW', 'lat': '41.63277817'}, {'city': 'Vinton', 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'lon': '-92.02583313', 'icao': 'KVTI', 'lat': '42.21860886'}, {'city': 'Monticello', 'state': 'IA', 'country': 'US', 'lon': '-91.16329956', 'icao': 'KMXO', 'lat': '42.22036362'}]}}, 'zip': '52401', 'wmo': '99999', 'country_iso3166': 'US', 'country_name': 'USA', 'wuiurl': 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/IA/Cedar_Rapids.html', 'magic': '1', 'state': 'IA', 'tz_short': 'CST', 'l': '/q/zmw:52401.1.99999', 'lat': '41.97171021', 'lon': '-91.65871429'}, 'response': {'termsofService': 'http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html', 'version': '0.1', 'features': {'conditions': 1, 'geolookup': 1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response. Script looks match better

Comment: Why does one need proxies? It seems I would need to use a public proxy as those are the only ones that are free?